# How do I convert these characters to their readable form

Tags: oracle

I have some columns in my oracle database table which is having some `��` in them.

How do I decode it to it's original readable form.

I know it's is related to encoding but I need to find a solution for this.

In my php application I get those characters as plain '??'.

I am using sql developer to view records.

Comment: Use `convert` function to convert from codepage of the text to codepage of your database.

Comment: running the query "SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';" give me this : "NLS_CHARACTERSET","AL32UTF8".
Then I ran this query but it gave the same result (no conversions made) : "select convert(column_name, 'AL32UTF8', 'utf8') from table_name;"

Comment: I don't know what is the language and codepage of your text.  Just an example: `convert(column_name, 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P1')`

Comment: it is "AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8"

Comment: That is your database settings.  And what is the character set of your text?  Probably, `dump(column_name)` may shed some light on it.  Just compare numeric character values and detect your charset.

Comment: 'dump' gave me something like this
what shall I compare in it.
"Typ=1 Len=555: 84,104,101,32,102,117,110,100,32,110,111,114,109,97,108,108,121,32,105,110,118,101,115,116,115,32,97,116,32,108,101,97,115,116,32,56,48,37,32,111,102,32,105,116,115,32,110,101,116,32,97,115,115,101,116,115,32,105,110,32,101,113,117,105,116,121,32,115,101,99,117,114,105,116,105,101,115,32,111,102,32,108,97,114,103,101,32,109,97,114,107,101,116,32,99,97,112,105,116,97,108,105,122,97,116,105,111,110,32,85,46,83,46,32,99,111,109,112"

Comment: This text may not be displayed incorrectly - it consists of Latin alphabet letters only and is valid UTF-8 text: "The fund normally invests at ..."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28496/discussion-between-gaurav-sharma-and-egor-skriptunoff)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert them from UTF8 to your current encoding. Or vice versa.

Comment: these characters are copyright sign, trademark sign.

I cannot change them directly with a simple regexp sql.

I want them to be converted to their readable form in database.